# PHP SQLSRV Error using machine account

Tags: php, windows, authentication, sqlsrv

I am using SQLSRV function using windows authentication but it is using the machine account as a default. How can I change it? I want to run using  HOMESBUILD\john.davis

I am running PHP 5.3.10 on WAMP Server 2.2

Error Message: 
Connection could not be established.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'HOMESBUILD\KKK-454-IAH05$'.

Answer (score 0):

I had to configure the WAMP server from Services to run as different account.